# how to mount internal hd after booting with external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, startup, disk-utility, external-disk, mount

I am running macosx 10.6.3 and trying to mount/access the internal hd through diskutility: it does not show up here. I tried this:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/23/view-mount-hidden-partitions-in-mac-os-x/

What could be the reason why I cannot access my internal hd anymore?

Comment: Not quite clear from your question… when booted from an external drive, the internal will not show on DU? Will it still boot from the internal drive? Does it show if you hold Opt at the chimes? If still no, can you at least hear it spin up at boot?

Comment: Won't boot from internal disk that is what I am trying to fix but won't show up in  DU

Comment: Yes it is spinning and showing when using options at boot